# Access PHP page from C# WinForm

Tags: c#, php, winforms

I have an IIS enabled server (LAN) but with **no** support for PHP. I need to access an existing PHP page on the server. Without making any changes to the server, how can I access the PHP page using C# in my Windows Form project?

Comment: what you want to do using this page?q

Comment: How to access PHP from C# on a server with no PHP support? Tried [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @DeveloperJigarPandya Existing page was having Phone Extensions + Voice Port numbers, new migrated server (unused computer) does not have php support, can't install, I Want to use/display this page in the winform so that I need not create new page from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you want to execute the PHP script using C# right? I guess you can use the  [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) for this. phalanger allows you to  calling functions written in PHP and working with PHP objects in the legacy mode.

The problem however is that these functions will get called to cater your needs but not flush the HTML from PHP Script to meet your needs;

The thing you are looking for is that you want the script to be generated using some server software (IIS or LAMP) but you don't have that tool right?

I guess this will not be possible